# Is it a good practice to copy database from SD card in application itself once the application starts?

Tags: android, database, sd-card

I don't want the SD Card to be removed by user when my application is running, as it will contain the database I would be using in my application for displaying images and information from it.

Possible solutions as I see can be to copy the contents of the Database in SD card into the application at the start of the application (but it might consume time).

Is there any particular way by which I can freeze my application when the SD-Card is removed ?

Thanks for your help in advance !

Cheers, 
Sumit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about don't have the database on the SD card in the first place? If you are downloading it, download it directly to internal storage. If it is inside the APK as an asset or resource, extract it to internal storage.

If you need to use external storage (SD card), check if external storage is mounted when the app starts. If it is not, display an appropriate message and finish the activity.

Comment: thanks for your reply

my database is pretty big and it will be upgraded at a centralized place so that anyone with the application can download it when it is upgraded, hence I feel it is best to use SD card, I have already taken care of things suggested in your 2nd statement

Comment: My main concern is that when my application is running how to detect if the user removes SD card or the SD card gets to a state where I cannot read/write it, as unable to detect so will lead the application to crash and I don't want that to happen

Comment: Is there a method which will keep checking like every second that the SD card is present and when it is removed or anything it will display a dialog box saying database is not accessible.

Comment: Of course not :) Every second is excessive. If you don't want it to happen, catch exceptions and act accordingly. It is very unlikely that they will remove the SD card while interacting with your application. Most probably, they will do something (copy pictures, etc.) and come back to your app while the SD card is not available. If you put your checks in `onResume()` that should handle it.